# How to map columns fetching flat-file data from a table in my database and not from a file in SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

In ssis package i want to map columns fetching,fixed width data from a table in my database and not from a file.
I know to do the same from using File Connection Manager.But i want to use my table as the source and not the file.

i have used OLE DB Source tool box as source and written a SQL query that will give me a row.

now i have to map the columns according , as we get a grid in File Connection Manager.

Are there any ways to do this without using Derived columns tool ?

Value in the table is FIXED-WIDTH data.

Comment: I think that it would be easier to write a View to parse the fixed-width data into View columns using SUBSTRING and then use that as a table-source in SSIS.  That’s how I’ve always done it.

Answer (score 1):

Write a proper SQL Select so you can retrieve the values already split. It will way easier to do this in SQL than using derived columns on SSIS, both for readability and maintenance.

For an example on `SQL Server` you can use `SUBSTRING` against the fixed width column:

```
SELECT
    FixedWidthColumn1 = SUBSTRING(T.FixedWidthColumn, 1, 20),
    FixedWidthColumn2 = SUBSTRING(T.FixedWidthColumn, 21, 15),
    FixedWidthColumn3 = SUBSTRING(T.FixedWidthColumn, 36, 14),
    FixedWidthColumn4 = SUBSTRING(T.FixedWidthColumn, 51, 19),
    FixedWidthColumn5 = SUBSTRING(T.FixedWidthColumn, 70, 100)
FROM
    YourTable AS T
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant.